# Find window with variable caption

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I'm using WinApi and C#. I need to find window with variable caption. Caption contains constant part. I think that I need to enumerate all windows. How I can do this?

Comment: There is already a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032933/enumerate-all-window-handles-on-desktop) .

Answer (score 1):

you have to use P/Invoke function: [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Look for EnumWindows in MSDN - it accepts callback function, in which you get list of all windows